# what is the purpose of @Context and @Parallel annotation

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I have few beans which needs to be initialized either parallely or eagerly and to do this while reading the docs of micronaut, I noticed @Parallel annotation which can be used to initialize beans parallely and I came across @Context annotation which I am not able to understand clearly.

As for as my understanding is concerned, @Parallel annotation will shutdown the application if any of the beans executing simultaneously fails whereas @Context will not even startup the application if there is any failure.

I just wanted to check if this correct? Also, if I want to do eager initialization of bean rather than on-demand which annotation is the best one to use?

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: "if I want to do eager initialization of bean rather than on-demand which annotation is the best one to use?" - `@Context`

Answer (score 1):

When you annotate a bean using the `Context` annotation, it simply means that the bean gets initialised earlier and eagerly (with the Application Context) than beans annotated with e.g. `Singleton` or `Prototype`.

> Context scope indicates that the bean will be created at the same time as the ApplicationContext (eager initialisation)

With these annotations you define the *scope* of your bean within the application context.

`Parallel` does not define a bean scope, but as you found out yourself behaves accordingly to `Context`.

As a rule of thumb: If you have beans that need to start early, with the application context, annotate them using `@Context`.
If you have a singleton bean with a slow startup path declare it with `@Singleton` and `@Parallel`.

This is how I understud the documentation.

Comment: is there any specific ordering of annotation between Singleton and  Parallel annotation to be followed?

Comment: No, there is no ordering required. The presence of the annotations is, what the magic triggers